# why is This method constant() in php is giving me warning

Tags: php

```
const MyConstant = "test";
$declaredcons = "MyConstant";
echo constant ($declaredcons);//Emits me warning why???
echo constant ("MyConstant");//How ever not working 
echo MyConstant;//Outputs test .I dont want to use this...
```

Iam trying to know why it is giving me warning when i const(constantname).Can any one has tried it .Iam using 5.3.6 on windows 7. Is It bug?

Comment: Just tried your code on my 5.3.6 install and no warning.

Comment: The warning Warning:  constant() [function.constant]: Couldn't find constant MyConstant in file....

Comment: I got this: testtesttest

Comment: Might be My php build has broken .....

Comment: who is the person that has given down vote?

Comment: works for me, I used phpsh to test, my php version is "PHP 5.3.3-7+squeeze3 with Suhosin-Patch (cli)"

Comment: hey Derby, mind telling me why my answer below is not suiting you ? also downvoting so many answers is not a good this.

Answer (score 1):

You should only use `const` inside an CLASS . outside classes it is prefered to use `define()` 
Try something like this :

```
define("MyConstant", "test");

$declaredcons = "MyConstant";

echo constant ($declaredcons); // result : test
echo constant ("MyConstant");  // result : test
echo MyConstant;               // result : test
```

Inside a class you CAN use const :

```
class MyClass
{
    const constant = 'constant value';

    function showConstant() {
        echo  self::constant . "\n";
    }
}

$class = new MyClass();
$class->showConstant();
```

Answer (score 0):

https://www.php.net/constant

Take a look at this page.  The warning you are seeing is indicating that the constant is not properly declared.